# D3D11 Create Shader: Encoded Vertex Shader size doesn't match specified size

Tags: c++, rendering, directx-11, vertex-shader

I am working on a game engine using DirectX 11 and am having trouble getting shaders to encode properly. I am precompiling shaders to .csh files and creating shaders with the byte codes.

I get this error when I try to create any shader, but for this example I will use my PassThrough vertex shader.

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader: Encoded Vertex Shader size doesn't match specified size. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #166: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERBYTECODE]
```

The Shader:

```
#include "../VertexLayouts.hlsli"
// structs in included file
struct PASS_THROUGH_VS
{
    float3 pos : POSITION;
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD;
};

struct PASS_THROUGH_PS
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD;
};


PASS_THROUGH_PS main( PASS_THROUGH_VS input )
{
    PASS_THROUGH_PS output = (PASS_THROUGH_PS)(0);
    output.pos = float4(input.pos, 1);
    output.texCoord = input.texCoord;
    return output;
}
```

with these settings:
[PassThrough_PS properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVVx5.png)

In Renderer.h

```
#include "Vertex Shaders\PassThrough_VS.csh"
```

In Renderer.cpp

```
HRESULT hrReturn;

    hrReturn = CreateVertexShader(&PassThrough_VS, sizeof(PassThrough_VS), Pass_Through_VS);
    if (FAILED(hrReturn)) {}
        //return hrReturn;

HRESULT CRenderer::CreateVertexShader(const void* ptrByteCode, SIZE_T szByteCodeLength, eVertexShaderType type)
{
    HRESULT hrReturn;
    tVertShader newShader = {};
    hrReturn = D3Device->CreateVertexShader(&ptrByteCode, szByteCodeLength, nullptr, &(newShader.m_id3dShader)); // WHERE ERROR OCCURS
    if (FAILED(hrReturn))
        return hrReturn;
    newShader.m_ptrByteCode = ptrByteCode;
    newShader.m_szByteCodeLength = szByteCodeLength;
    D3VertexShaders[type] = newShader;
    return hrReturn;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it with every shader model, updated my drivers and gone back and tried a trivial vertex shader which worked before but not now.

Comment: Another question would be what is the reason for .cso or .csh? I was taught how to use the .csh method but can't for the life of me remember what the reasons the teacher gave. Also it seems that it is a very rare technique as there is nothing on google or bing concerning that file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are passing a pointer-to-a-pointer, so you aren't actually passing the shader blob data to Direct3D.

```
HRESULT CRenderer::CreateVertexShader(const void* ptrByteCode, SIZE_T szByteCodeLength, eVertexShaderType type)
{
    HRESULT hrReturn;
    tVertShader newShader = {};
    hrReturn = D3Device->CreateVertexShader(&ptrByteCode, szByteCodeLength,
        nullptr, &(newShader.m_id3dShader));
    ...
```

The correct code is:

```
HRESULT CRenderer::CreateVertexShader(const void* ptrByteCode, SIZE_T szByteCodeLength, eVertexShaderType type)
{
    HRESULT hrReturn;
    tVertShader newShader = {};
    hrReturn = D3Device->CreateVertexShader(ptrByteCode, szByteCodeLength,
        nullptr, &(newShader.m_id3dShader));
    ...
```

> You should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) in particular.

You didn't include any details about the `tVertShader` type, but you could well have reference counting problems. Consider using `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` instead of raw pointers for managing the lifetimes of Direct3D COM objects. See [this article](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).

Comment: Thank you for the response. i'm currently at work so it'll be a bit before i can try the solutions. it's true i have reference problems and i was using comptrs before but i seem to have a multiple places where resources are being misallocated. in the tVertex struct the shader is being held by an ID3D11 shader pointer and the byte code is a const void*.